# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 - Get rows not present in other side of relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I've got 2 entites, with its setters and getters:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SRC\PurchaseBundle\Entity\Purchase", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_purchases",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="purchase_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $purchases;

    ...
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="purchases")
 */
class Purchase
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @var users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SRC\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="purchases")
     */
    protected $users;

    ...
}
```

I'd need to select all missing purchases for the user.
I've already achieved this by getting all existing purchases and checking, one by one, they doesn't exist in `$user->getPurchases()`.

Does exist a better way to get this results?

Is there a way so I could create a method inside USER entity called `getMissingPurchases()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="{name_of_column}", referencedColumnName="{name_of_fk_column}")
```

Comment: Hi mask8! Thank you for your reply, but I already set this annotation. I´ve updated the code, pasting the real thing.